# Smart Gwt equivalent of gwt's Root Panel.?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

what should be used in Smart Gwt in Place of Root Panel in Gwt?

Comment: Can you improve your question a little bit ?

Comment: @Jean-MichelGarcia there is no need for improvement his question is quite clear

Comment: @AdelBoutros, for me it's not really clear. In some cases, you have to use RootPanel.get("").add instead of SmartGWT draw method. That's why I asked for more information on what was he trying to achieve

Comment: @Jean-MichelGarcia No No No. RootPanel is strictly for GWT. NEVER use it with smartgwt. Instead you add the components and for the main component, you call the draw method

Comment: @AdelBoutros in a page that contains not only SmartGWT, how do you indicate that you want to draw inside a specific DIV ?

Comment: @Jean-MichelGarcia This is the point. SmartGWT was made to NOT mind about CSS and html. Maybe then SmartGWT is not the technology you want. Do you develop Swing components inside C# elements?

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to use GWT's `RootPanel`.

To add / render widgets to the document, simply call `BaseWidget#draw()`. See how it's done on the [SmartGWT's showcase](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_summaries_featured_category).

#### Reference

- [`draw()` on the SmartGWT API docs](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_summaries_featured_category)

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you will need to still use RootPanel to draw your objects. This is the case for example if you are embedding your SmartGWT application into a portlet or into a page that already have non SmartGWT contents.

In a general way of thinking, calling `draw` is the best and the proper way of drawing SmartGWT objects.

However, for the reasons specified above, you can still use

```java
VLayout mainLayout = new VLayout();
RootPanel.get("myDIV").add(mainLayout);
```

Keep in mind that calling RootPanel.get().add involves GWT DOM manipulation.